# iphone timer plist file display

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm going to ask this question again,I thought I had figured it out but I guess not. This is for a timer app that gets the timer info from a plist file. Everything works but I want the .plist extension not to show in my tableview. Here are two code snippets that I believe are the issue. These are in an array called `NSArray *files;`

```
self.files = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"plist" inDirectory:@"Timers1"];

// Configure the cell.

cell.textLabel.text = [[files objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] lastPathComponent];
return cell;
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *text = [[files objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] lastPathComponent];
text = [text substringToIndex:[text rangeOfString:@"."].location];
cell.textLabel.text = text;
```

Comment: That worked thank you! now if I can just figure out my tile based game problem I would really be happy

Comment: if my answer solved your problem you should accept it by click on the tick beside the answer .. in stackOverFlow we say thank u by accepting the answers :))